# Flex: Hide (or Remove) Label Text without Changing the Button Size

Tags: apache-flex, text, button

I have a button with variable-length of label text.  I have a User Setting that can turn on or off the label text on this button.

How can I implement this?

NOTE: the button's background has a gradient color.

I tried using BlendMode.LAYER, no luck;

I tried using Button.resizeHandler

```
    private function resizeHandler(event:ResizeEvent):void
    {
        if (event.oldWidth > this.width)
            this.width = event.oldWidth;
        if (event.oldHeight > this.height)
            this.height = event.oldHeight;
    }
```

but it only worked if the initial UserSetting value is true.

How about embedded font? I don't know how to apply it to button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend mx.controls.Button to add a show/hide label function. The text field is a protected property so you can just set the visibility on/off in your function. Leave Flex to measure everything correctly itself.

If you want to grow/shrink the button when the text is on or off, you can also set the button width. You will have to calculate the width based on the textfield width.

Comment: finally I gave up working on the button itself.  I extended a canvas and put two buttons to simulate what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property minWidth and maxWidth. minWidth to specify the minimum width that the button should have. and maxWidth to specify the maximum width the button can have.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you just set the button's width?  That way, it should be a constant width no matter what you set as the label.

Most likely width is being calculated in the updateDisplayList method.  So, code in your resize handler may be being reset at the next render event.

Comment: I want to have different width for buttons with different text, so there is no way to get the width.

Comment: @Peter Lee: So, what behavior do you want?  If you don't want to specify a fixed button width, I only see to behaviors that fit your need: Grow the button to the longest text, but never shrink... OR allow the text to wrap within the button.  Aside for fixing the width to a large size, it is not clear what you actually want this button to do.

Comment: @Peter Lee look into the getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight() and getExplicitOrMeasuredWidth() methods or the measuredWidth / measuredHeight .  If you set the width and height to measuredWidth and measuredHeight respectively when the label on the button; it should retain proper sizing when the label is removed.  ( Assuming you have code to prevent the resizing when the label is not there).